# asp.net core web api (.net 6) created project with startup.cs instead of program.cs

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Trying to open a aws serverless application asp.net core web api project with program.cs
As it should be in .net 6

Can anyone explain why when I open a project of this type:
aws serverless application with test (.net core c#)
[image]
and choosing:
asp.net core web api
[image]
A .net 6 project was created that contains a startup.cs instead of program.cs??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because AWS team has not migrated their templates to the new minimal hosting model and use the previous generic hosting one (the one with the `Startup`), which is actually perfectly fine (at least at the moment) and is fully supported by the framework.

Read more:

- I assume source code for this templates can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet)
- [Custom templates for dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) - if you want you can always create templates customized to your needs
- [.NET Generic Host in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#nhm)